# Cannot autowired DataSource into WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Trying to add jdbc auth into spring-boot app

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String databaseDriverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String databaseUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String databasePassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(databaseDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(databaseUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);

        return dataSource;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

All examples tell that is enough, but @Autowire doesn't work

IDEA tells "Could not autowire. No beans of DataSource type found"

project structure

```
com.acsent
    config
        WebSecurityConfig.java

    Application.java
```

Comment: What are the packages of your classes ?

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
@ComponentScan("com.acsent")
```

to

```
public class WebSecurityConfig
```

solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in a whole different way.
Using db access through hibernate. 
You can see sources at [github](https://github.com/acsent80/miniEShop)